# is there a function that can partially apply arguments on a function with order?

Tags: elisp, functions

`apply-partially` cannot specify the order.

Is there one from the default Emacs installation that can specify order?

Comment: Please consider showing how you would use such a function, to make clear what you mean by "specify the order".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something more general/flexible than `apply-partially`, then there's `lambda`:

```
(lambda (x y z) (funcall F A B y x C D z))
```

you'll want to make sure you have `-*- lexical-binding:t -*-` at the top of your file for that, tho.